# is it possible to have a select statement in the resultset of a linq query?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

I have a query like the following:

```
select column_a, (select column_a from table_b where b.column_c = a.column_c) column_b
from table_a a where a.test = 1 order by a.number
```

I know I can perform joins in linq but is there something similar like this in linq ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a straightforward translation of the SQL statement:

```
from a in table_a
where a.test == 1
orderby a.number
let column_b = (from b in table_b where b.column_c == a.column_c select b.column_a).SingleOrDefault()
select new { a.column_a, column_b }
```

Keep in mind that this is a nested loop, so it has quadratic performance if it's a simple LINQ to Objects query. In the T-SQL example, the optimizer knows how to turn the subquery into a join anyway.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation. This clarifies a lot. accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'Join' method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx

In declarative syntax:

```
from item_a in table_a
join item_b in table_b on item_a.column_c equals item_b.column_c
where item_a.test == 1
orderby item_a.number
select new {column_a = item_a.column_a, column_b = item_b.column_a};
```

And in method syntax:

```
table_a.Where (item_a => item_a.test == 1)
  .Join(table_b,
    (item_a) => item_a.column_c,
    (item_b) => item_b.column_c,
    (item_a, item_b) => new { column_a = item_a.column_a, column_b = item_b.column_a });
```

See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4a91b6320a53e37633de) for a runnable LinqPad snippet.

Comment: As the OP wrote: "I know I can perform joins in linq but is there something similar like this in linq ?"

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. The answer shows something similar in linq syntax. Did you want it written in .Method style?